# C preprocessor token substitution fails with parse error

Tags: c, assembly, c-preprocessor, inline-assembly

I have defined the following macros in my **C** program:

```
#define ISE1  "cust_add"
#define ISE2  "cust_sub"

#define ise_inst(inst, a, b, c) \
asm volatile (
" " inst " %1, %2, %0          \n\t" \
: "=r" (c) \
: "r" (a), "r" (b) \
: "%g0" \
)
```

In the main routine, I call the macro with the following parameters:

```
ise_inst(ISE1, inp1, inp2, res);
```

Ideally, the preprocessor should expand the whole thing so that I get the following result:

```
asm volatile (
" cust_add %1, %2, %0          \n\t"
: "=r" (res)            
: "r" (inp1), "r" (inp2)         
: "%g0"                                                   
);
```

Anyone an idea what I did wrong? At the moment the pre-processor tells me

> error: parse error before string constant (@ line: " " inst " %1, %2, %0  \n\t" )

Comment: You might consider changing the question to something like "C preprocessor token substitution fails with parse error". The question "Preprocessor replacement" sounds like you want to replace the preprocessor--I'm pretty sure I've seen questions like that within the last couple of weeks.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're missing a `\` line continuation character after the `asm volatile(` line.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the missing `\`, your assembler instruction must be stringified like this:

```
#define ise_inst(inst, a, b, c)       \
asm volatile (                        \
" " #inst " %1, %2, %0          \n\t" \
: "=r" (c)                            \
: "r" (a), "r" (b)                    \
: "%g0"                               \
)
```

Note the little `#` before `inst`. If you then call your macro with `ISE1` this will expand to `"ISE1"`.

Comment: thanks guys, it was very helpful all your comments. It works now!

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget about backslash character (`\`) after `asm volatile (` ?